# MySQL query for searching by address when the address is split over multiple fields

Tags: mysql

I have slimmed things down for example purposes.

I have three MySQL database fields in a table called "property";

```
property_house_number
property_street_name
property_postcode
```

I have a page that allows the client to search for a property by address. This page has three input fields that correspond to the MySQL database fields;

```
Property House Number:
Property Street Name:
Property Postcode:
```

At the moment, if my client wanted to search for the address "1 Church Road, L15", he would enter the following into the input fields;

```
Property Number: 1
Property Street Name: Church Road
Property Postcode: L15
```

My client wants there to be just one input field where he can simply enter "1 Church Road L15". The client may also just want to search using one part of the address, e.g. just "Church Road" or just "L15".

Is there a MySQL query that allows for this?

Comment: _Is there a MySQL query that allows for this?_ Yes there will be

Comment: In general, no, there is no way to do what your client wants.  Just break the address across some number of fixed fields, then have the search UI match that structure with one input box per field.

Comment: You could concatenate the 3 columns and then use a LIKE to search them, would that not work @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @RiggsFolly Big problems with that, because 2 different fields could become identical when concatenated together.  The OP's suggestion should be avoided.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Not totally sure I understand that comment, but for clarity, I was not considering making a new column on the DB, but just concatenating the columns in a query.

Comment: `1 Willow Lake` + `Village, US` = `1 Willow` + `Lake Village, US` ... not a perfect example, but you see where this is going

Comment: *if my client wanted to search for the address "1 Church Road, L15"* ```.. WHERE (property_house_number, property_street_name, property_postcode) = (1, 'Church Road', 'L15')```. *client may also just want to search using one part of the address* Construct the conditional expression dynamically, or check that the value is provided (something like ```.. AND (column = 'value' OR 'value' = '') ..```).